# error .match expression results null

Tags: merge, match

I am working on a mail merge script. I have used Logger.log to find out that the error is in the expression that tells match what to find. In my case I am trying to pull all the keys that are inside ${xxxxxxx}. Below is what I have and I need help cleaning it up because at this point it returns null.

```
var template = "This is an example ${key1} that should pull ${key2} both keys from this text."
var templateVars = template.match(/\$\{\"[^\"]+\"\}/g);
```

Thanks for any guidance anyone can share on this problem.

-Sean

Answer (score 0):

I am not really familiarized with Google Apps Script, but I think this code in Javascript can help you.

It looks for all the ocurences of `${key}` and returns each value inside the `${ }`. I think that is what you are looking for.

```
var template = "This is an example ${key1} that should pull ${key2} both keys from this text.";
var matches  = template.match(/\$\{[0-9a-zA-Z]*\}/mg);
console.log(matches);
for ( var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++ ) {
    console.log(matches[i].replace(/[\$\{|\}]/gm, ""));
}
```

Comment: No that didn't help I am still getting a null value on the line that has matches.length. When I log template before that line it has all the string with the appropriate ${word} tags, but the next line Log shows matches.length is null.

Comment: Could you please paste the code you have? On the code I posted it works great. And a real template string, please